# 2019 T2 I9 MacBookPro - linux boot external drive

Tags: external-disk, unix

I have a triple boot set up on T2 Macbook Pro.

macOS, Windows 10, Arch Linux boot off of the internal NVMe drive, which works fine. I also have an external TB enclosure Orico with a NVMe drive set up with Arch and an EFI partition, but for some reason it doesn't show up on the LSBLK list, nor does it show up on the list of available boot options when restarting the MBP using the <kbd>Option</kbd> keypress.

It does show up on macOS `diskutil` and in Windows.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried setting custom volume label for external SSD's EFI using `bless` ([as described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444554/rename-windows-boot-camp-volume-in-startup-manager))?
2. Have you tried executing [bootoption](https://github.com/bootoption/bootoption) (i.e. `bootoption list`)?
3. Have you tried switching to [rEFInd+](https://github.com/dakanji/RefindPlus) boot manager?

Comment: Updated the answer with rEFInd+ as an other option. I'm not sure if that might be the case, but Apple's common boot loader may be missing NVMe driver for external drives somehow? Don't mind rEFInd+'s explanation states it's primarily for legacy Macs. It contains a ton of improvements over rEFInd and perhaps a fix to your situation.

Comment: Partial Success !!  I mounted the EFI partition found it was empty of bootloaders, so I copied them from the working EFI partition on the internal disk.  This booted into grub rescue.  I suspect I need to adjust the linux root partition that the boot loader tries to mount but I haven't the first clue on how to do this.